# Neo4j Unexpected thread death and Java heap space

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Hey guys please I need help with this error. My graphdb has been malfunctioning.
When I ping the server, I get response but I cannot fetch record from the database. When I checked the neo4j.log file, I found this:

```
2018-11-15 11:30:05.106+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.4.9 ========
2018-11-15 11:30:05.196+0000 INFO  Starting...
2018-11-15 11:30:09.036+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2018-11-15 11:30:11.024+0000 INFO  Started.
2018-11-15 11:30:12.079+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://132.148.17.240:7474/
2018-11-15 17:37:32.940+0000 WARN   Java heap space
2018-11-15 17:37:32.955+0000 WARN   Java heap space
2018-11-15 17:37:32.955+0000 WARN  Unexpected thread death: 
2018-11-15 17:37:32.955+0000 WARN   Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2018-11-15 17:37:32.956+0000 WARN  Unexpected thread death: 
2018-11-16 11:14:04.730+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

This is my neo4j configuration:

```
GNU nano 2.0.9                                                              File: /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

#*****************************************************************
# Neo4j configuration
#
# For more details and a complete list of settings, please see
# https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/
#*****************************************************************

# The name of the database to mount
#dbms.active_database=graph.db


# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically
# calculated based on available system resources.
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size.
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=4G
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=12G

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files, in bytes (or
# kilobytes with the 'k' suffix, megabytes with 'm' and gigabytes with 'g').
# If Neo4j is running on a dedicated server, then it is generally recommended
# to leave about 2-4 gigabytes for the operating system, give the JVM enough
# heap to hold all your transaction state and query context, and then leave the
# rest for the page cache.
# The default page cache memory assumes the machine is dedicated to running
# Neo4j, and is heuristically set to 50% of RAM minus the max Java heap size.
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g
```

Thanks so much guys.

Comment: do you know what query  was running at `17:37:32` ?

Comment: How much memory do you have to work with for that server? Is the server's only purpose to host Neo4j, or are there any other memory-intensive processes running

Comment: @InverseFalcon 32GB RAM to run PHP and GraphDB

Comment: @logisima No I don't sir.

Comment: You may want to enable [query logging](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/logging/query-logging/) to monitor for long-running queries. Bad queries combined with low heap can result in what you're experiencing, and you can usually see a high number of GC operations in the debug log. You're likely going to want to profile your queries and optimize them to be more efficient, and you may need to add batching as well using APOC Procedures (see [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate))

Comment: can you check also the content of the `debug.log` ?

Comment: I found out I had a query running indefinitely. So I added [dbms.transaction.timeout](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.transaction.timeout) to timeout the query.

Thanks guys.